# Facebook login doesn't work after release when facebook app is installed

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, key, release

My application was working successfully before publishing it on google play . But after publishing it , login button works only when facebook application is uninstalled.

I have generated the release hashkey using the signed key store

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

Is there anything I am missing ?
Are there any special configurations in facebook application to  allow users to login in the app using facebook while facebook app is installed ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Bluel3ull for your answer but this wasn't the problem.
The problem was in the hashkey .. for some reason the hashkey that I got from writing this command

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

wasn't right.

So this is how I get the right hashkey.
I have force the app to open web login always by adding this line

```
loginButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

Then I tried to post something to facebook wall. Here a facebook error occurred and nothing was posted to facebook. When I displayed the error in a Toast, I found the right hashkey that must be in my facebook application.
Then I deleted

```
loginButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

The application now is released and every thing is working fine.

I hope this will help any one who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

this may help and it may not. 
I think it may be a intent problem but don't hold my word on it good luck.
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html

Important: i suggest making a backup copy before editing any thing...... don't find out the hard way like me.